# Missing the point of LU factorization / decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, gaussian-elimination, lu-decomposition

### Gaussian Elimination

The system of linear equations $Ax = b$ may be solved by using [Gaussian Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) (GE) arriving to a Row Echelon Form **R** of the augmented matrix $[A b]$, and then using back-substitution.

### LU Decomposition

Another way to solve $Ax = b$ is to use [LU Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition). It follows the same procedure than GE, but it records the Elimination steps (inverse) into a matrix **L**, and does not augment $A$. So it just involves operating on $A$.

One could describe it as:

$A \rightarrow_{E_1} B \rightarrow_{E_2} C \ldots \rightarrow_{E_n} \rightarrow U$

And in compact manner $E_n\ldots{}E_2E_1 A =  U$ or just $E_{total} A = U$ and then also $ A = E_{total}^{-1} U $, where the new $E^{-1} = L$

It seems this would still require solving $Ux=Eb$, but I may be wrong.

### Comparison

LU has some extra work compared to plain GE:

1. Record the elimination changes
2. Get the inverse of $E$ i.e $L$ (but in this case inverse seems straight forward)

- LU allows easy calculation of the determinant $det(A) = det(L) det(U)$ as compared to GE, since GE calculates as

[image]

where $d$ is the product of constants and also signs (details in the wikipedia article.)

- LU does not take the $b$ into account, $b$ is not appended onto $A$, which makes the solution more general/robust.

On the other hand, GE uses an expanded matrix with $b$ appended as a column, which means that for another $b$ and same **A** [we would be repeating calculations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1588135/benefits-of-lu-factorization).

### Question

- Are these the reasons to do LU decomposition i.e that we reuse U for more $b$s just by applying $Lb$ and that we can compute D(A) more easily ?
- Is this even correct ?

---

I've read this related posts, none actually asks this exact question I think [first](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75173/lu-factorization-decomposition), [second](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1588135/benefits-of-lu-factorization).

Comment: The computational cost of computing the LU factorization of $A$ is the same as the cost of doing Gaussian elimination ($O(n^3)$ in either case), but once we have an LU factorization of $A$ we can use it to solve $Ax = b$ inexpensively ($O(n^2)$ cost) for many different choices of $b$.

Comment: Yes @littleO , though I just realised it still requires solving $Ux = Eb$ right?

Comment: Yes, to solve $LUx = b$ we first solve $Ly = b$ and then solve $Ux = y$. But these are easy because $L$ and $U$ are triangular (so the cost is just $O(n^2)$).

Comment: I read that in Wikipedia, $Ly=b$ and then $Ux =  y$ but can't get why. PS: Oh, I did get why, sorry. @littleO